# ASP.net w/ C# RadiobuttonList doesn't trigger a postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, radiobuttonlist, autopostback

I'm currently building a webform, that uses a dropdownlist and a radiobuttonList, among other things. There is some small validation, if you select a value on either of these elements, there has to be a postback and certain elements may have to be reloaded, depending of the bussiness logic. 
Now I created eventHandlers for both the RBL and DDL, but I have a problem.

If I change the value on the DDL, the postback is triggered and the program loops through my method, no problem. If I change the value on the RBL, the postback is not triggered, not at all. The weird part is, if I first change something in the RBL and then something in the DDL, it does loop through both event handlers, in the correct order.

But obviously this isn't ideal for me. If the user changes something in the DDL first and later in the RBL, the program won't function properly.

I will post my code below, does anyone know how to make a RadioButtonList trigger a postback/eventhandler?

C#

```
protected void SchoolTypeID_Index_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code
    }

protected void ddlStudentenStad_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code
    }
```

ASP.net

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStudentenStad" DataTextField="stad" DataValueField="id" AutoPostBack="true" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStudentenStad_IndexChanged" runat="server" class="SelectDropDown"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSchoolType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="type" 
DataValueField="id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SchoolTypeID_Index_Changed" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"/>
```

EDIT: we have also made a RadioButtonListAdapter class, cause we've had more problems with this element in the past. The code is pasted below, if anyone would happen to see the error.

public class RadioButtonListControlAdapter : ControlAdapter
{

```
public RadioButtonListControlAdapter()
{
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    RadioButtonList ButtonList = Control as RadioButtonList;

    if (null != ButtonList)
    {
        int i = 0;

        if (ButtonList.RepeatDirection == RepeatDirection.Horizontal)
        {
            writer.WriteFullBeginTag("div class=\"row collapse\"");


            int aantalCols = (int)Math.Floor((double)12 / (double)ButtonList.Items.Count);
            foreach (ListItem li in ButtonList.Items)
            {
                string itemClientID = Helpers.GetListItemClientID(ButtonList, li);

                writer.WriteFullBeginTag("div class=\"large-" + aantalCols + " columns\" style=\"width:" + 100/ButtonList.Items.Count + "% !important; \"");

                writer.WriteFullBeginTag("label for=\"" + ButtonList.UniqueID + "\"");
                if (ButtonList.TextAlign == TextAlign.Right)
                {
                    RenderRadioButtonListInput(writer, ButtonList, li);
                    RenderRadioButtonListLabel(writer, ButtonList, li);
                }
                else
                {
                    RenderRadioButtonListLabel(writer, ButtonList, li);
                    RenderRadioButtonListInput(writer, ButtonList, li);
                }
                writer.WriteEndTag("label");

                writer.WriteEndTag("div");
                if (this.Page != null)
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(ButtonList.UniqueID, li.Value);
                //if (ButtonList.RepeatDirection == RepeatDirection.Vertical)
                //    writer.Write("<br />"); 
                writer.WriteLine();
            }

            writer.WriteEndTag("div");
            if (this.Page != null)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(ButtonList.UniqueID);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (ListItem li in ButtonList.Items)
            {
                string itemClientID = Helpers.GetListItemClientID(ButtonList, li);
                //writer.WriteFullBeginTag("div class=\"row\"");
                writer.WriteFullBeginTag("label for=\"" + ButtonList.UniqueID + "\"");
                if (ButtonList.TextAlign == TextAlign.Right)
                {
                    RenderRadioButtonListInput(writer, ButtonList, li);
                    RenderRadioButtonListLabel(writer, ButtonList, li);
                }
                else
                {
                    RenderRadioButtonListLabel(writer, ButtonList, li);
                    RenderRadioButtonListInput(writer, ButtonList, li);
                }
                writer.WriteEndTag("label");
                //writer.WriteEndTag("div");

                if (this.Page != null)
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(ButtonList.UniqueID, li.Value);
                //if (ButtonList.RepeatDirection == RepeatDirection.Vertical)
                //    writer.Write("<br />"); 
                writer.WriteLine();
            }
        }


        if (this.Page != null)
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(ButtonList.UniqueID);
    }
}

private void RenderRadioButtonListInput(HtmlTextWriter writer, RadioButtonList ButtonList, ListItem li)
{
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, Helpers.GetListItemClientID(ButtonList, li));
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "radio");
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, ButtonList.UniqueID);
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Value, li.Value);

    writer.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "none");
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "hidden-field");
    if (li.Selected)
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Checked, "checked");
    if (li.Enabled == false || ButtonList.Enabled == false)
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Disabled, "disabled");
    if (li.Enabled == true && ButtonList.Enabled == true && ButtonList.AutoPostBack)
    {
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick, String.Format(@"javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'{0}\',\'\')', 0)", Helpers.GetListItemUniqueID(ButtonList, li)));
    }
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Input);
    writer.RenderEndTag();
}

private void RenderRadioButtonListLabel(HtmlTextWriter writer, RadioButtonList ButtonList, ListItem li)
{
    writer.WriteFullBeginTag("span class=\"custom radio\"");
    writer.WriteEndTag("span");      
    writer.Write(" " + li.Text);

}
```

}

Comment: What's the 'class' you mean in your DropDownList?.

Comment: that's just something css related, I don't think that's important to autpostback tbh

Comment: Is your databind code inside the `IsPostback` check in your `Page_Load`?

Comment: No that doesn't work. Inside my page_load the data is bound inside a if (!(Page.IsPostBack)) statement

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your controls with an update panel.

You can also dig through the code or post more details. The reason why events doesn't trigger is probably some additional logic, not shown in your code listing. I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: My partner has the same problem, he has tried an update panel, but that doesn't work.

I doubt it'll be additional code imho. DDL works. I've just heard we've made a RadioButtonList adapter, maybe that one interferes somehow. I'll post the code in my post

Comment: I'm almost certain it's caused by the adapter.